# tail recursion recognition

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I stumbled upon the following:

```
myAdd (x:xs) = x + myAdd xs
myAdd null = 0

f = let n = 10000000 in myAdd [1 .. n]

main = do
 putStrLn (show f)
```

When compiling with GHC, this yields a stack overflow. As a C/C++ programmer, I would have expected the compiler to do tail call optimization.

I don't like that I would have to "help" the compiler in simple cases like these, but what options are there? I think it is reasonable to require that the calculation given above be done without using O(n) memory, and without deferring to specialized functions.

If I cannot state my problem naturally (even on a toy problem such as this), and expect reasonable performance in terms of time & space, much of the appeal of Haskell would be lost.

Comment: Just for the record: That function is not tail-recursive.

Comment: You'd have to actually make a tail recursive function to expect optimization - try making an accumulator argument for your myAdd in order to make an easily understandable version.

Comment: You can't state all problems "naturally" and expect reasonable performance in any language.

Comment: This link might interest you: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-February/003396.html

Comment: You guys are right to point out that this is not tail recursion, sorry about that.

The question remains why GHC cannot optimize this in a way that doesn't require O(n) memory.

Comment: It's hard for GHC to know when you want laziness and when you want strictness. Once you get into the feel of laziness, you'll understand why it is like this and, hopefully, come to appreciate the different benefits. :-)

Comment: "As a C/C++ programmer" - sir to learn Haskell, you first must unlearn some things. If you expect Haskell to behave like C, you are in for a world of hurt. The way function calls work is completely different, for one thing. If you instead try to learn Haskell from scratch, I think you'll find it to be quite intriguing and intuitive.

Comment: @Dan: I am prepared to unlearn many things, but that is not the issue here. The issue is why the compiler is unable to optimize something that appears to be rather trivial to optimize.

Comment: Legitimate question; I'm not sure why some people express their questions as criticisms of the language they are using. Is there nothing to be gained from learning a language, faults and all?

Comment: @luqui: this is not a criticism of Haskell. It does have implied criticism of a specific compiler (GHC), but I don't think that is unwarranted in this case?

Comment: reddish: This optimisation would change the semantics of the language and this is highly undesirable for any language. What you need to learn is that there are a lot of patterns which you can express with functions that already exist, in this case fold'. What functions like fold' show is that it's possible to almost write optimisations in the language itself (and even more so with GHC, which supports optimisation annotations; used for things like list fusion etc.). nponeccop's example below is a perfect example; C's semantics would be changed significantly if the foldr performed like Haslell's

Comment: @Axman6: "This optimisation would change the semantics of the language and this is highly undesirable for any language" -- that's a weird statement to make I think. A defining property of a proper optimization is that it does not change semantics; and we're usually talking about the semantics of a given concrete program. I still don't see why my particular program needs to run in O(n) space.

Comment: It may be weird, but it's certainly a [true statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8671693/1598537). If you wanted it to run in O(1) space, why not use `foldr` or even `sum`?

Comment: @luqui Yes, it's the classic "I'm new to this language and I made a program that does something wrong, but I'm right and it's the compiler's fault. Clearly this is a stupid language, not even basic stuff works."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you're compiling with `-O2`. It makes a lot of performance problems just go away :)

The first problem I can see is that `null` is just a variable name there. You want `[]`. It's equivalent here because the only options are `x:xs` and `[]`, but it won't always be.

The issue here is simple: when you call `sum [1,2,3,4]`, it looks like this:

```
1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + 0)))
```

without ever reducing any of these additions to a *number*, because of Haskell's non-strict semantics. The solution is simple:

```
myAdd = myAdd' 0
  where myAdd' !total [] = total
        myAdd' !total (x:xs) = myAdd' (total + x) xs
```

(You'll need `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` at the top of your source file to compile this.)

This accumulates the addition in another parameter, and is actually tail recursive (yours isn't; `+` is in tail position rather than `myAdd`). But in fact, it's not quite tail recursion we care about in Haskell; that distinction is mainly relevant in strict languages. The secret here is the *bang pattern* on `total`: it forces it to be evaluated every time `myAdd'` is called, so no unevaluated additions build up, and it runs in constant space. In this case, GHC can actually figure this out with `-O2` thanks to its strictness analysis, but I think it's usually best to be explicit about what you want strict and what you don't.

Note that if addition was lazy, your `myAdd` definition would work fine; the problem is that you're doing a *lazy* traversal of the list with a *strict* operation, which ends up causing the stack overflow. This mostly comes up with arithmetic, which is strict for the standard numeric types (Int, Integer, Float, Double, etc.).

This is quite ugly, and it would be a pain to write something like this every time we want to write a strict fold. Thankfully, Haskell has an abstraction ready for this!

```
myAdd = foldl' (+) 0
```

(You'll need to add `import Data.List` to compile this.)

`foldl' (+) 0 [a, b, c, d]` is just like `(((0 + a) + b) + c) + d`, except that at each application of `(+)` (which is how we refer to the binary operator `+` as a function value), the value is forced to be evaluated. The resulting code is cleaner, faster, and easier to read (once you know how the list folds work, you can understand any definition written in terms of them easier than a recursive definition).

Basically, the problem here is not that the compiler can't figure out how to make your program efficient — it's that making it as efficient as you like could *change its semantics*, which an optimisation should never do. Haskell's non-strict semantics certainly pose a learning curve to programmers in more "traditional" languages like C, but it gets easier over time, and once you see the power and abstraction that Haskell's non-strictness offers, you'll never want to go back :)

Comment: I am sure its a minor typo. "foldl' (+) 0 [a,b,c]" is expanded as "((0 + a) + b) + c"

Answer (score 9):

Expanding the example ehird hinted at in the comments:

```
data Peano = Z | S Peano
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Peano where
    compare (S a) (S b) = compare a b
    compare Z Z = EQ
    compare Z _ = LT
    compare _ _ = GT

instance Num Peano where
    Z + n = n
    (S a) + n = S (a + n)
    -- omit others
    fromInteger 0 = Z
    fromInteger n
        | n < 0 = error "Peano: fromInteger requires non-negative argument"
        | otherwise = S (fromInteger (n-1))

instance Enum Peano where
    succ = S
    pred (S a) = a
    pred _ = error "Peano: no predecessor"
    toEnum n
        | n < 0 = error "toEnum: invalid argument"
        | otherwise = fromInteger (toInteger n)
    fromEnum Z = 0
    fromEnum (S a) = 1 + fromEnum a
    enumFrom = iterate S
    enumFromTo a b = takeWhile (<= b) $ enumFrom a
    -- omit others

infinity :: Peano
infinity = S infinity

result :: Bool
result = 3 < myAdd [1 .. infinity]
```

`result` is `True` by the definition of `myAdd`, but if the compiler transformed into a tail-recursive loop, it wouldn't terminate. So that transformation is not only a change in efficiency, but also in semantics, hence a compiler *must not* do it.

Comment: The compiler could specialize for the invocation with regular integers, though (?)

Answer (score 7):

A little funny example regarding "The issue is why the compiler is unable to optimize something that appears to be rather trivial to optimize."

Let's say I'm coming from Haskell to C++. I used to write `foldr` because in Haskell `foldr` is usually more effective than `foldl` because of laziness and list fusion.

So I'm trying to write a `foldr` for a (single-linked) list in C and complaining why it's grossly inefficient:

```
int foldr(int (*f)(int, node*), int base, node * list)
{
    return list == NULL
        ? base
        : f(a, foldr(f, base, list->next));
}
```

It is inefficient not because the C compiler in question is an unrealistic toy tool developed by ivory tower theorists for their own satisfaction, but because the code in question is grossly non-idiomatic for C.

It is not the case that you cannot write an efficient `foldr` in C: you just need a doubly-linked list. In Haskell, similarly, you can write an efficient `foldl`, you need strictness annotations for `foldl` to be efficient. The standard library provides both `foldl` (without annotations) and `foldl'` (with annotations).

The idea of left folding a list in Haskell is the same kind of perversion as a desire to iterate a singly-linked list backwards using recursion in C. Compiler is there to help normal people, not perverts lol.

As your C++ projects probably don't have code iterating singly-linked lists backwards, my HNC project contains only 1 `foldl` I incorrectly wrote before I mastered Haskell enough. You hardly ever need to `foldl` in Haskell.

You must unlearn that forward iteration is natural and fastest, and learn that backward iteration is. The forward iteration (left folding) does not do what you intend, until you annotate: it does three passes - list creation, thunk chain buildup and thunk evaluation, instead of two (list creation and list traversal). Note that in immutable world lists can be only efficiently created backwards: a : b is O(1), and a ++ [b] is O(N).

And the backward iteration doesn't do what you intend either. It does one pass instead of three as you might expect from your C background. It doesn't create a list, traverse it to the bottom and then traverse it backwards (2 passes) - it traverses the list as it creates it, that is, 1 pass. With optimizations on, it is just a loop - no actual list elements are created. With optimizations off, it is still O(1) space operation with bigger constant overhead, but explanation is a bit longer.

Comment: I see your point, but ... whether to use left or right folding is not a matter of perversion. The point is the function one folds over the list. With associative functions it doesnt matter, but if you have f :: b -> a -> b and a list of a you'll probably want to fold left.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two things I will address about your problem, firstly the performance problem, and then secondly the expressive problem, that of having to help the compiler with something that seems trivial.

**The performance**

The thing is that your program is in fact not tail recursive, that is, there is no single call to a function that can replace the recursion. Lets have a look at what happens when we expand `myAdd [1..3]`:

```
myAdd [1,2,3]
1 + myAdd [2,3]
1 + 2 + myAdd [3]
```

As you can see, at any given step, we cannot replace the recursion with a function call, we could simplify the expression by reducing 1 + 2 to 3, but that is not what tail recursion is about.

So here is a version that is tail recursive:

```
myAdd2 = go 0
  where go a [] = a
        go a (x:xs) = go (a + x) xs
```

Lets have a look at how `go 0 [1,2,3]` is evaluated:

```
go 0 [1,2,3]
go (1+0) [2,3]
go (2 + 1 + 0) [3]
```

As you see, at every step, we only need to keep track of
one function call, and as long the first parameter is 
evaluated strictly we should not get an exponential space
blow up, and in fact, if you compile with optimization (`-O1` or `-O2`)
ghc is smart enough to figure that out on its own.

**Expressiveness**

Alright so it is a bit harder to reason about performance in haskell, but most of the time you don't have to. The thing is that you can use combinators that ensure efficiency. This particular pattern above is captured by `foldl` (and its strict cousin `foldl'`) so `myAdd` can be written as:

```
myAdd = foldl (+) 0
```

and if you compile that with optimization it will not give you an exponential space blowup!

Comment: It is perfectly clear to there are better ways to write what I did in Haskell; I am just a wee bit disappointed that the version as I wrote it apparently cannot be sanely optimized by the current flagship compiler.

A similar program in C with ...

`int sum(int from, int to) { return (from > to) ? 0 : from + sum(from + 1, to); }`

... is optimized to an iterative version from -O2 upwards. The Haskell equivalent:

`mySum from to = if (from > to) then 0 else from + (mySum (from + 1) to)`

is not, at least using ghc -O2. My first program is just a fancy version of that.

Comment: ..apart from your C code not generating a large linked list, traversing it forwards, building up nested thunks left to right then evaluating them right to left, I suppose it is the same. Please first understand how Haskell code is evaluated, and don't expect to be able to guess; learn. Your guess was wrong. No need to complain.